# Covnert geometry_msg/StampedPoint to Stamped pose

Tags: ros, pose, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys.

I'm trying to convert point to pose.
But i don't know how to do.
I saw topic_tool package, but the only example is about stg_msgs. I can't find parameteres that i need. :(
And i also saw 'covert pose to point' (https://answers.ros.org/question/249104/convert-geometry_-msgspose-to-point/)
The answer is so simple. But it's not for me.

Thanks you for your interest, Ray.

(edit)
Code

rosrun topic_tools transform /clicked_point /clicked_pose geometry_msgs/PoseStamped \

'geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped( \

```
header=m.header,  \
pose=geometry_msgs.msg.Pose( \
  position=m.position, \
  orientation=geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion( \
orientation.x = 0.0 \
    orientation.y = 0.0 \
orientation.z = 0.0 \
orientation.w = 0.0 \
)))' \
```

--import geometry_msgs

Error

[ERROR] [1597812518.884135, 258.643000]: bad callback: <bound method TopicOp.callback of <**main**.TopicOp instance at 0x7fac8a25ef38>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/raptor/nav_ws/src/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/home/raptor/nav_ws/src/ros_comm/tools/topic_tools/scripts/transform", line 94, in callback
res = eval("{}".format(self.expression), self.modules, {'m': m})
File "", line 7
orientation.y = 0.0 
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359658/covnert-geometry_msg/stampedpoint-to-stamped-pose/) by [Ray_Shim](https://answers.ros.org/users/56592/ray_shim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `transform` from `topic_tools`. It is quite useful yet handy tool for which you have to care about. You can see the details of paramters [here](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform).
Here is an example to use in launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node name="diagnostics_stamped" pkg="topic_tools" type="transform"
    args="/diagnostics /diagnostics_stamped diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray 
   'diagnostic_msgs.msg.DiagnosticArray(header=std_msgs.msg.Header(
    stamp=rospy.Time.now(), frame_id=m.name),
    status=[diagnostic_msgs.msg.DiagnosticStatus(
    level=m.level, name=m.name, message=m.message, hardware_id=m.hardware_id, values=[])])' 
    --import diagnostic_msgs std_msgs rospy"/>
</launch>
```

To run an from terminal an example can be seen [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/261935/using-topic_tools-transform-to-publish-more-complex-types/)

---

Originally posted by [Tahir M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23517/tahir-m./) with karma: 213 on 2020-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ray_Shim](https://answers.ros.org/users/56592/ray_shim/) on 2020-08-18**:
Thanks for your help. But i'm still stuck.

I face problem that i don't know how to write orientation part. I cannot find any reference about orientation.
I want to put all 0.0 values in orientation. So I made some simplse code. But i got error msg about syntax.

Could i get some advice about my code? (i upload my code)